# 'System.Exception.HResult' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the the following error in my code.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'System.Exception.HResult' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I have one class in my `App_Code` folder and using `LogException()` method of that class to insert exception details to database.

Business access layer reference is already given to this class for accessing functionality.

I tried it in in my local machine and local IIS, it is working fine. but when i am hosting it  on windows server IIS then it is giving me error.

Please help me to solve this problem.

**Updated:**

Below is my function in `App_Code/Exception.cs` class and I referenced the Business Access Layer in this class.

```
public static void LogException(Exception ex, string userId, string refPage, string appName)
{
    try
    {
        ExceptionManager objEx = new ExceptionManager(); // this is business class
        objEx.InsertErrorLog(userId, appName, ex.HResult, ex.GetHashCode(), ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace, refPage);
    }
    catch {
        DestroySession();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even in your local machine there is no way you can call a protected setter outside the object itself. Besides, why are you trying to set HResult in the first place? If it comes from another exception, save this exception

Comment: It's much easier to understand what's going on and point you in the right direction of you show the actual code that causes the error.

Comment: I am trying to get the error code, not setting it.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev - I added the code for your reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to set the `HResult` property of the `Exception`. You can't do this as it's setter is [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult.aspx). If you need to set this property then your only alternative is to derive a new type of `Exception` e.g.

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException(string message, int hresult)
        : base(message)
    {
        HResult = hresult
    }
}
```

---

Seems to me your actual issue is a difference in .NET versions between your dev / deployment environments. The `HResult` property was *completely* `protected` up until 4.5. The reason you are seeing this once deployed, I assume, is because you are running under an older version of .NET.

You will need to install .NET 4.5 on your deployment machine.

Comment: If you *need* to set this, do it in a descendant class.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah, no worries I removed mines as well.

Comment: I am just passing the Exception as parameter to that method and using ex.HResult to get the error code for logging in DB.

Comment: public static void LogException(Exception ex){ // using ex.HResult to get error code & passing it to db}

Comment: @Chirag if you are only *getting* the HResult then you wouldn't get the warning. It's only if you are attempting to *set*.

Comment: @James - you are right; and my current code is working fine in local IIS. I am having a problem after deploying it to Live Windows Server.

Comment: @james - Thanks a lot. I just installed framework 4.5 on server and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 8):

Update to .NET 4.5.

Or call [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gethrforexception(v=vs.90).aspx).

The code from the original post, with this change:

```
public static void LogException(Exception ex, string userId, string refPage, string appName)
{
    try
    {
        ExceptionManager objEx = new ExceptionManager(); // this is business class
        objEx.InsertErrorLog(userId, appName,
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(ex),
                ex.GetHashCode(), ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace, refPage);
    }
    catch {
        DestroySession();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I hadn't realised my old project was on .NET 4.0 when this error brought me here. When I upgraded the project application tab to .NET framework 4.6 the error went away

Comment: Note that GetHRForException also sets up an IErrorInfo - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gethrforexception?view=net-8.0